# Magento 2 : how to perform operation after product price update from backend

Tags: magento2, product, cart, magento2.3.2

I have added the product into the cart and want to send email to the customer after the same product's price change from the backend.

Comment: what operation you want to perform ?

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad please check updated description.

Comment: you actually want to send emails to customers who added products in their cart but did not checkout yet (product is in their quote)

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad yes and email send on backend product price update.

Answer (score 0):

You need to elaborate your question to get proper answer. Like - **What kind of Operation do you want to perform and when you need to perform after product price updated from the backend?**

One such example - If you want to update the product price of the item added to the cart then you should use Object Manager:

```
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
$priceHelper = $objectManager > create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data');
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
```

Comment: please check updated description.

Answer (score 0):

You may listen to

> catalog_product_save_after

event and start comparing the new and old value to trigger an email sending event.

Magento 2 seems to have native feature for product alerts.
[image]